# WiX Standard Dialogues

Tags: dialog, wix, windows-installer, wix3

Does anyone know if there are any WiX standard UI dialouges out there that you can use to integrate into your own WiX msi package?

For example:

- Editing Connection Strings to database
- Editing paths to log files in web.config/app.config
- Setting up users for a Windows Service
- Setting up WCF Endpoint addresses and other parameters

This would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've haven't seen any UI dialog package either.

[WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) has a dialog editor which I've heard is pretty useful, but I haven't used.
[War Setup](http://warsetup.jgaa.com/) is a pretty good utility.  It's been about a year since I've used it, so I don't remember if it has a dialog editor or not.

Edit: I couldn't think of the one I really loved, but I just found it: [WixAware](http://www.wixaware.com/).  It has probably the best dialog editor.  The only thing is that it's trialware and the full version is $800.

Answer (score 0):

Not today no. They aren't that hard to write though.